# Bouncycastle library join bytes and string

Tags: java, java-me, md5

Hi I'm using Bouncycastle library to create md5 hash from image byte array and client id string. But from Recognize.im API I'm still getting error invalid hash, is there anything wrong?

```
String myMd5(String myString, byte[] byteArray){
    MD5Digest md5 = new MD5Digest();
    md5.reset();
    try {
        md5.update(myString.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0 , myString.length());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    md5.update(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    byte[] digest = new byte[md5.getDigestSize()];
    md5.doFinal(digest, 0);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; ++i) {
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString((digest[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100)
                .substring(1, 3));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```